# excel table variable query

Tags: php, html, mysql, excel

I have a hurdle I need to try to overcome. I have a very large database I need to display in separate little excel tables on a website using html.

I know the structure of how to show an excel table on html code as well as the data inside each cell, but my tables I need to be created will vary in number of rows based on the number of columns of a row of data.

As an example one row with a unique primary key has 18 columns that need to be displayed as column 1 = cell A1, column 2 = cell B1, column 3 = cell A2, column 4 = B2, column 5 = A3.... etc. In the end it will be 9 cells tall and 2 cells wide.

The next table will have 26 columns, the next would have 6 columns... etc.

I think I need to send a query to my mysql database to ask how many columns are in the current queried row, then use that result as variable to build each table to an appropriate size?

I am totally lost at how to approach this. Maybe I need some sub script to run to build each table data string before making it html?

Help!

Comment: Impossible to answer unless you provide some information on how you're generating the HTML...  PHP? ASP? something else?

Comment: Generated by a php script I will execute on page refresh. It is a section of a website that I just generate text that fills in a page. Whatever I store in the row of the database will be shown on the site exactly as is. If I put in html code, it shows html formating.

Comment: If you run a query against mySQL then you should be able to get a count of the number of fields in the resulting recordset e.g. using `mysql_num_fields`. Your question is a little hard to follow: it's not clear for example what this has to do with Excel, since you seem to be generating HTML tables...

Comment: Ok, understood. What I am having difficulty wrapping my head around, is how code the statement to CONCAT all the data to one row. The data needs to be all stored in one data location, but able to make a 6 row table or an "$number_fields" row table, and associate the data to each "cell". I'm not sure if I am explaining this correctly.

Comment: Unless you show some code, it's difficult to make suggestions.  I doubt anyone is going to write for you from scratch, but people here generally are willing to "improve" your existing code.

Comment: Hey Tim, I will put something together in an hour or to to show what I am attempting to do, and where I am stuck.

Comment: OK - I am not a php person, but I re-tagged your question with `PHP`, so that may get you more help.

Comment: Alright, I will post my code in a little while, although broken it works. My issue is let's say I have a maximum of 80 Rows. If I make a script to fill 160 "cells", the next table only has 8 rows with 16 cells. If I use the same script it will generate 160 cells, 80 rows tall, with only 16 filled in the first 8, the rest are blank. I need a script to use the $number_fields data to change how many cells are generated. I made a script to make 160 cells, I will post it in a bit